# OAuth + PKCE expects the code verifier to be sent from the client-side, so isn't the code verifier exposed?

Tags: security, oauth, client-side, pkce

I am implementing OAuth2 with authorization flow + PKCE for a single page web application. My question is, in the [flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#section-4.1) described, it is stated that the code verifier is sent to the authorization server from the client-side of the application. Then, doesn't that mean the code verifier is exposed?

I have been told that anyone could view the content of the variables, the code used, etc. on the client-side part of a single page application. Then, what prevents a malicious actor to retrieve the code verifier the moment it exists on the client-side part of the application?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

PKCE protects against a specific vulnerability. If a malicious actor is able to read an entire webpage, client state, etc then PCKE is not going to help you.

The specific vulnerability PKCE protects you against is if *something* can intercept the redirect. One example is a redirect back to a native phone application. If a malicous application was installed and intercepts this redirect, the `code` alone is useless because they need the `code_verifier` which lives in the app that originally initiated the `authorization_code` flow.